# git commit hash in zsh prompt

Tags: command-line, git, zsh, prompt

I'd like to see the current commit hash (just the first 8 or so characters) in my zsh prompt.

I have this so far: https://github.com/calebmeyer/cpm-zsh-theme/blob/master/cpm.zsh-theme#L3

```
git_commit_hash() {
  if [ -d .git ]; then
    git log -1 --pretty=oneline | cut -c -8
  fi
}
```

When I source the file, (via `. ./cpm.zsh-theme`), I see the commit hash for the current commit. However, it doesn't update when I change directories or make changes/commits. This also means that when I load up the theme on prompt start, there's no commit hash (and that never updates)

Here's a screenshot: [image: my prompt!]

How can I get zsh to re-evaluate this function on every new prompt?

Note: I'm using oh-my-zsh and antigen to manage my config. You can see my dotfiles here: https://github.com/calebmeyer/dotfiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROMPT='other prompt stuff .. $(git_prompt_short_sha) more stuff '
```

Looking at what you linked though, the problem might just be that you're using double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Single quotes worked, and caused my commit_hash to be re-evaluated on every prompt. Exactly what I was looking for! You can see the results [here](https://github.com/calebmeyer/cpm-zsh-theme/blob/master/cpm.zsh-theme#L38)